# unable to solve code error

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    return days*140

def plane_ride_cost(n):
    if n == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif n == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif n == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif n == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost-=50
    elif days >=3 and days <7:
         cost-=20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(n)+hotel_cost(days)
```

I input the code above and get various errors, one of which is:

```
trip_cost('Tampa', 5) raised an error: global name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: @Sayse By editing out the part about Code Academy, you've made it unclear where the "Oops, try again" part of the error comes from.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - In that case, that "Oops, try again" should probably be removed also.

Comment: @Sayse You're making it worse. That is not a standard Python exception message.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - What do you mean? a simple google search for "global name 'n' is not defined" returns multiple duplicates. There isn't anything specific to codeacademy here.

Answer (score 2):

The error is raised from this line:

`return rental_car_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(n)+hotel_cost(days)`

You are invoking function `plane_ride_cost` with a variable `n` which is not defined in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

In `trip_cost`, you're calling

```
 plane_ride_cost(n)
```

But `n` is not defined there. Did you mean `city`?

Comment: more like 'city' than 'days'

Comment: @Dschoni Of course, thank you. Edited.